# Performance issue migrating from Richfaces 3.3.x to PrimeFaces 10.0.0

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, richfaces

I'm working migrating a legacy software that use a lot of cases like `<ui:repeat var="area" value="#{areaList.getResultList()}">`. Where `getResultList()` executes a DB query. One of the problems is that when an ajax call is made, JSF at the phaseId 2 (APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES) visit all `UIViewRoot` children, and executes this DB queries.

The question is, there is a way to avoid this? Is correct to think when the request is an ajax  type, don't visit all children. Is a JSF / JSF 2 issue or Primefices issue? The migration also include JSF 1 to JSF 2 (Mojarra)

(I have zero chance to modify the way of `value` is retrived)

**UPDATE:**

I'm using Wildfly 25.0.0 (it comes with jsf 2.3 by def) and JSF 2.1 Mojarra_2.1.29. But if you observe the stack when de ui:repeat is being accessed:

[image]

PartialViewContextImpl belong to JSF 2.3 (not mojarra_2.1.29) and there is where the original problem is, I think.

The strange is when the app starts, the log says:

```
INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) Inicializando Mojarra 2.1.29
```

I followed the next doc to configure a new JSF implementation on Wildfly: [Link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/JSF%20Configuration.html)

**UPDATE**

I've extended UIRepeat and then solved my problem:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

Comment: No, I know about that behavior, but in my case is an ajax request where the ui:repeat is not going to be updated. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't see any PrimeFaces code here just `ui:repeat` so are you sure its not a change when you upgraded did you upgrade Mojarra versons? Server versions?  Can post more code showing PF is the issue?

Comment: I think the problem is related with JSF version. I've updated the question.